# How can I delete mySQL to start fresh? (OSX)

Tags: mysql, macos

Whenever I use:

```
cat /etc/my.cnf
```

it looks like this:[image]

As you can see it comes out blank. On top of this I tried to reset my password and I went and screwed everything up. NOW I Just want to restart from scratch. I don't need to save anything I have no database info that I am worried about losing I am just trying to get mySQL working.

**TL;DR:**

I just want to reset everything/delete all things to do with mySQL to get a fresh start. I have tried all of the rm commands and reinstalling it but that didn't even work. I don't have anything that I need to save or back up.

Comment: see if there is a default version of my.cnf in your mysql directory. on my machine it's in /usr/local/mysql. You can copy it to /etc

Comment: @johnelemans I found /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf how would I copy that into /etc

Comment: sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf /etc/my.cnf

Comment: How you remove MySQL depends on how you installed it. How did you install MySQL?

Comment: @Schwern I installed it using the Mac OS X 10.10 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: This is more about a Mac specific installation issue. I would suggest you try asking this on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it from the [MySQL Community Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) everything should be in something like `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.10-x86_64/`. The exact directory name depends on your version of MySQL and OS X.

Delete that directory and reinstall the package. That should reset everything.

---

Alternatively you have *multiple* copies of MySQL installed and they're confusing each other.  Check with `which mysqladmin`.  If it points to somewhere other than inside `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.10-x86_64/` then you have another version installed.

Comment: I can get into ls /usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/ but when I use the command 'which mysqladmin' it returns /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin

Comment: @Lenny You either have two copies of MySQL installed, or `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin` is a symlink to `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/bin/mysqladmin`. Check with `ls -l /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin`.

Comment: @Lenny Juuust to make sure, did you check MySQL is running in the MySQL preference pane?

Comment: MySQL wont even start, thats partially why I am doing this right now. When I try to start it through the preference pane it prompts me for my password and I enter it but nothing happens

Comment: @Lenny That this point you'll probably have to go into the Console and find the mysql log to figure out what's going on. I can't debug this for you remotely. Maybe try on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)?